# Segger Embedded Studio not expanding macros for post build script

Tags: ide, script

I am trying to run a post-build script in Segger Embedded Studio (v6.20a).

I want to have access to variables that are Macro-defined in SES.
Example variable is NRFUTIL, which should expand to a filepath.

Based on [this forum post](https://forum.segger.com/index.php/Thread/7268-SOLVED-User-defined-macros-expansion/) from Segger, Macros that are defined at the global or project level should be accessible by pre or post build scripts.

I have confirmed that I have NRFUTIL defined globally:
[image]

But, I am unable to access it from a post build script:

[image]

Why can't my script find my global macro?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using curly braces instead of parentheses around your variable names: `${NRFUTIL}` instead of `$(NRFUTIL)`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found that worked for me was to explicitly pass the necessary macros to my script as parameters when the script is called.

My post build command:

```
../Post_build/post_build.sh $(NRFUTIL) $(ProjectDir) $(ProjectName) $(Configuration) $(SigningKey)
```

Then, in my post build script, I pass those parameters to local variables within my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NRFUTIL=$1
ProjectDir=$2
ProjectName=$3
Configuration=$4
SigningKey=$5

Application_file_path=$ProjectDir/Output/$Configuration/Exe/$ProjectName.hex
DFU_zip_file_path=$ProjectDir/../Post_build/Outputs/$Configuration/DFU_package

echo "Generating DFU package."
nrfutil pkg generate --application-version 1 --application $Application_file_path --hw-version 52 --sd-req 0x0103 --sd-id 0x0103 --key-file $SigningKey $DFU_zip_file_path/$ProjectName.zip
```